# How to create a customized navigation bar like the following app?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am developing an app to be similar to the following app:
[image]

In the green box, I believe it is just a `UICollectionView` with 2 `UICollectionViewCells` per row and I achieved it writing some sample code like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    var imageName = [UIImage(named: "1"), UIImage(named: "2"), UIImage(named: "3"),
                     UIImage(named: "4"), UIImage(named: "5"), UIImage(named: "6"),
                     UIImage(named: "7"), UIImage(named: "1"), UIImage(named: "2"),
                     UIImage(named: "3"), UIImage(named: "4")]
    var nameArray = ["name 1", "name 2", "name 3",
                     "name 4", "name 5", "name 6",
                     "name 1", "name 2", "name 3",
                     "name 4"]

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return nameArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.imgImage.image = imageName[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblName.text! = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let width = collectionView.frame.width / 2 - 1

        return CGSize(width: width, height: 80.0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 1.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 1.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let MainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let desCV = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
        desCV.getImage = imageName[indexPath.row]!
        desCV.getName = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(desCV, animated: true)

    }
}
```

This achieved the following:

[image]

I am trying to find out how to duplicate the navigation bar design, if it is a custom navigation bar to begin with?

There is a settings and weather button on the top right corner, so I don't believe it is a navigation bar, but once again I'm not sure.

If the navigation bar was customized, I'm not sure why it doesn't appear in the segued view controller, for example:

[image]

What I've tried to do so far:

**1.**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let helperView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    helperView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    navigationItem.titleView = helperView
}
```

This lead to the navigation bar's height remaining static and width does not fill the view's width:

[image]

**2.**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    let height: CGFloat = 300 //whatever height you want
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
}
```

Once again, the navigation bar height remained the default height.

Whatever was done seems to fill 25% of the view's height, and I would like to achieve the same result.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to use the collection view's supplementary view loading a .xib as follows:

```
class CustomHeader: UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet var customHeaderImageView: UIImageView!
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let headerNib = UINib(nibName: "CustomHeader", bundle: nil)
    sampleCollectionView.register(headerNib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CustomHeaderCell")
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGSize(width: 375, height: 100)

    return size
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
{
    switch kind
    {
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "CustomHeaderCell", for: indexPath)
            return headerView

        default://I only needed a header so if not header I return an empty view
            return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}
```

However, the results does not meet my requirements as the header is added below the navigation bar instead of taking over its place:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first photo I don't think it is a custom navigation bar but a collectionView supplementary view (in this case a header) :https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618037-collectionview.

First create your header cell

```
class myCollectionViewHeaderView: UICollectionViewCell {
 ....
}
```

then register the cell in you collectionView:

```
myCollectionView.register(myCollectionViewHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: myCollectionViewHeaderViewCellId)
```

implement the delegate method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: SCREENW, height: headerHeight)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: myCollectionViewHeaderViewCellId, for: indexPath)
    return headerView
}
```

Hope it helps

**For the update**

Put that in your viewWillAppear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

// Put the following lines if you want to keep the slide to pop even if the navigation bar is hidden    
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
}
```